# Keep anchor tag from changing styles

Tags: css, html

Quick question out of curiosity that I'm not finding clear material on, if I (using html5 of course) wrap a `container div` with an `anchor tag` such as `<a href="#"><div> </div></a>` with the div and its children already styled, can I keep the new anchor from changing the styles?

In example, the containers in my current situation are set with `floats` (I don't like the floats either, but it's a work edit to an existing page built by someone else). Wrapping them with anchor tags obviously breaks the floats. Sure, I can go in and style the anchor tags, or individually wrap each child of the container with the anchor but that becomes a hassle. Also the text inside the containers now has link-like attributes (such as text-decoration).

Is there a way to say "ignore that the link is here as far as styles go", or is that just another idealist fantasy on my part?

Comment: `div` in `a` is not correct syntax. Provide more code and fiddle.

Comment: no, it will not break any floats on the div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A link generally affects the text-decoration and color attributes, so just make the anchor tag inherit those:

```
#myAnchor {
  text-decoration: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: wouldnt `inherit` be if the anchor were inside the container with the relevant styles, or would the anchor tag inherit the children styles?

Comment: inherit means it just takes whatever style its parent has. So if its parent has black color and no text-decoration, the anchor will now take on those same styles.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to make the div a link/clickable is by using html javascript onclick attribute:

```html
<div class="clickable-div" onclick="location.href='#';"><div> ... </div></div>
```